# Display AutoField(primary_key) as read only in Django admin

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

My `models.py` has the following class:

```
class TodoList(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.id
```

`admin.py` contains the following lines:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from todolist.models import TodoList

class TodoListAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    readonly_fields = ('id',)

admin.site.register(TodoList, TodoListAdmin)
```

However, in the Django 1.5.1 admin the `id` is not shown as read only. Instead I am just displayed `(None)`. How can I automatically display the `id` of the object that I am creating as read only?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Generally It does not  have an ID until you save it.

Please follow below code it will sure help you to overcome from None(displayed data).

models.py

```
class A(models.Model):
    a = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.a)
```

admin.py

```
class AAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['a']
    readonly_fields = ['a_display']

    def a_display(self, obj):
        if obj.a is None:
            a = A.objects.all().order_by('-a')[:1]
            if a:
                return a[0].a + 1
            else:
                return 0
        else:
            return obj.a

admin.site.register(A, AAdmin)
```

Please check above code .if any issue please comment.

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't have an ID until you save it. If you're adding a new one, it is correct to show 'None'.

Comment: So there is no way to display the ID that the object will get?

Comment: There's no way of *knowing*. It's up to the database, and it doesn't decide until the moment the insert is made.